# How to solve set theory problem solving questions given a scenario

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Dennis gets a job at Sarah's ice cream shop as the V.P. of market research.He conducts a survey with a sample of 150 people and finds that...

94 people like vanilla ice cream
114 people like strawberry ice cream
12 people did not like strawberry or vanilla ice cream

How many people liked BOTH strawberry and vanilla ice cream ?

my work:

well there are  many ways you can solve this .I just like to do the math in my head. so first you subtract 94 with people who like vanilla subtract by 12 ,so 150-94-12=44
then for strawberry again,subtract 150 by 114 people subtract by people who didn't like strawberry or vanilla so ,150-114-12=24

then you add up vanilla and strawberry=44+24=68

answer: 68 people liked BOTH strawberry and vanilla ice cream

Comment: Have you tried checking this?  How many like vanilla only? How many like strawberry only?  Do your answers add up to $150$?

Comment: how would you solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$94+114+12-150=70$ so $70$ people like both flavors.

The justification for the calculation is that when we add the people who like vanilla and those who like strawberry, we count those who like both twice, and subtracting $150$ from the total gives us the number counted twice.

Comment: ok thank you ,that makes a little more sense,@saulspatz

Comment: @RanveerMasuta You're wecome.  If this answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so it no longer shows as unsolved.

Comment: ok,can you also help me with one last question,as its not letting me post it

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/qusWN0EEde5DNODtzLYcc585fpFw4ZfjhaPwL-wy8pdbauvdI-Bf-IvwgZ8q7t-KiXiUX6lyz6zmT9kNX8nQlbLCdbpFFpF_AStAV5d9sVAwu0ebc-4OVQPyyutt=w626

Comment: I got 24 as my answer

Comment: Please don't post new questions in comments.  Ask another question.